# Multiple field names in appengine search

Tags: python, google-app-engine, search

Is it possible to have multiple fields with same name in Appengine Search service?

Why would i need this?
An example if the document is a newspaper page and it consists of single news, I would create fields story, title, author.
It would work great and i would be able to query documents with title:"something", author:"something else", but what when you have multiple stories on the same page? Multiple titles?

If i create fields with names "title1", "title2" .. i'm unable to search with the query
title:"something"

If i put all titles in the same "title", when i search title, i'll get mixed results

If this is a stupid idea, or if this isn't possible, can someone recommend a better way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another field that groups the stories.

basically you would be creating a search document per story like:

```
title, author, news_id
hi   ,    max,       1
hello,    max,       1
world,     me,       1
sup  ,     me,       2
```

then you query when you are in news page 1 with hi hello world stories and want author max.
query: author: max and news_id: 1
query for title:
title: hello

so you need to break your search documents more to do what you want.

Comment: Can you be a little bit more specific?

Comment: ohh sorry didn't notice this. Basically you create new row per story then the news_id will be your group to query against like: news_id:100 and title: hello

Comment: there is no group by, so i can't search for multiple titles on the same page, or am i wrong?

Comment: with your answer i'm not able to do search without knowing news_id, if i don't know news_id i can't search title:something sup:something on the same news

Comment: In your question the document is the news page. So whatever id you'll be using there is going to be your news_id meaning you do know the id of the news before querying for stories. For general search you can skip news id.